# Create tag from field using regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am using logstash to collect my apache logs, and as such I have a field called `request_url` which contains values that look like:

```
POST /api_v1/services/order_service HTTP/1.1
POST /api_v2/services/user_service HTTP/1.0
```

I want to create separate tags containing on the API version and the service name, e.g.

```
POST /api_v1/services/order_service HTTP/1.1 -> ["v1", "order_service"]
POST /api_v2/services/user_service HTTP/1.0 -> ["v2", "user_service"]
```

How do achieve this in logstash configuration? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following grok filter, you can separate the components you need and then add the appropriate tags

```
filter {
   grok {
      "match" => { "message" => "%{WORD:verb} /api_%{NOTSPACE:version}/services/%{WORD:service}" }
      "add_tag" => ["%{version}", "%{service}"]
   }
}
```

The event you'll get will look like this:

```
{
       "message" => "POST /api_v1/services/order_service HTTP/1.1",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-06-07T02:52:01.136Z",
          "host" => "iMac.local",
          "verb" => "POST",
       "version" => "v1",
       "service" => "order_service",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "v1",
        [1] "order_service"
    ]
}
```